# Not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Everytime I use the Include extension, it would return an error when a value from included entity is used in the **WHERE CLAUSE**.

I included the **System.Data.Entity** which is the common answer but still have the same issue.

**Model:**

```
public partial class business_partner
{
public int id { get; set; }
public string accountid { get; set; }
}

public partial class order
{
public int id { get; set; }
public string doc_number { get; set; }
public int vendor_id { get; set; }
public int status { get; set; };

[ForeignKey("vendor_id")]
public virtual business_partner businessPartnerVendor { get; set; }
}

public IQueryable<order> GetOrder()
{
return (context.order);
}
```

**Query:**

```
_orderService.GetOrder()
.Include(a => a.businessPartnerVendor)  
.Where(o => o.doc_number == "Order Number"
&& o.businessPartnerVendor.accountid == "TEST"
&& o.status > 2 && o.status != 9).Count() > 0
```

**Exception:**

> The specified type member 'businessPartnerVendor' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: What does "it would break" mean?

Comment: Yeah, what's the error?

Comment: @GeorgiGeorgiev My apologies for my term. But what I meant was it would throw an error.

Comment: @John The error is "The specified type member 'businessPartnerVendor' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."

Answer (score 2):

Alas you forgot to write your requirement. Your code doesn't do what you want, so I might come to the incorrect conclusion, but looking at your code, it seems that you want the following:

> Tell me whether there are `Orders`, that
>   - have a value of `DocNumber` that equals "Order_Number",
>   - AND that are orders of a `BusinessPartnerVendor` with a value of `AccountId` equal to "TEST",
>   - AND have a value of `Status` which is more than 2 and not equal to 9.

The part "Tell me whether there are `Orders` that", was deducted by the fact that you only want to know whether `Count() > 0`

Your Count would have joined all elements, included all columns of BusinessPartnerVendor, removed all rows that didn't match your Where, and counted how many joined items were left. That integer value would be transferred, after which your process would check whether the value is larger than zero.

One of the slower parts of a database query is the transport of the selected data to from the Database Management System to your local process. Hence it is wise to limit the amount of transferred data.

Quite often I see people using `Include` to get the items that are stored in a different table (quite often a one-to-many). This will select the complete row. From the businessPartnerVendor, you only want to use property `AccountId`. So why select the complete object?

> In entity framework use Select to select properties you want to query. Only use Include if you want to update the fetched data.

```
bool areTestOrdersAvailable = orderService.GetOrder()
   .Where(order => order.doc_number == "Order Number"
       && order.businessPartnerVendor.accountid == "TEST"
       && order.status > 2 && order.status != 9)
   .Any();
```

Because of the virtual keyword in your classes (ans maybe some fluent API), entity framework knows about the one-to-many relation and will perform the correct join for you. It will only use SQL "TAKE 1" to detect whether there are any elements. Only one Boolean is transferred

**Some Advices about entity framework**

It is good practice to stick as much as possible to [the entity framework code first conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx) The more you do this, the less Attributes and Fluent API is needed. There will also be less discrepancy between the way Microsoft's usage of identifiers for classes, fields, properties, methods, etc and yours.

> In entity framework, all columns of a table are represented by non-virtual properties, the virtual properties represent the relations between tables (one-to-many, many-to-many, ...)

My advice would be: add the foreign keys to your classes, and stick to one identifier to describe one row in your tables.

So decide whether to use `business_partner` or `BusinessPartnerVendor` if they are in fact the same kind of thing

Add the foreign key:

```
// Every Order is the Order of exactly one BusinessPartner, using foreign key (one-to-many)
public int BusinessPartnerId {get; set;}
public virtual BusinessPartner BusinessPartner {get; set;}
```

This has the advantage, that if you want to select the Ids of all BusinessPartners that have one or more `Orders` that ..., you don't have to perform a join:

```
var businessPartnerIds = myDbContext.Orders
    .Where(order => ...)
    .Select(order => order.BusinessPartnerId)
    .Distinct();
```

Only one database table will be accessed